# Nextflow+Docker: No such file or directory, even though file exists

Tags: docker, docker-compose, filesystems, nextflow, nf-core

I am trying to run a nextflow pipeline inside a docker container. Out of necessity I mounted the socket of docker as a docker volume. This is my docker compose file:

```
pipeline:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./docker/pipeline/dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./nextflow:/home/app/nextflow
      - ./data:/home/app/data
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

In this way nextflow inside the container can download all docker images to run the pipeline.

When I run a nextflow pipeline, i.e. nf-core/sarek, after a while and after some downloaded docker images it gives me the following error:

```
Command exit status:
  127

Command output:
  (empty)

Command error:
  /bin/bash: .command.run: No such file or directory

Work dir:
  /home/app/nextflow/work/e5/83f1be41789e7aa1f5b7fbc19851fc

Tip: you can replicate the issue by changing to the process work dir and entering the command `bash .command.run`
```

If I enter inside the container, the file `.command.run` exists in the path provided by the message, i.e. `/home/app/nextflow/work/e5/83f1be41789e7aa1f5b7fbc19851fc`!

If I try to run `bash .command.run` inside of it, I get the same error message:

```
/bin/bash: /home/app/nextflow/work/e5/83f1be41789e7aa1f5b7fbc19851fc/.command.run: No such file or directory
```

This is the dockerfile I use:

```
FROM nextflow/nextflow:23.11.0-edge

RUN yum install -y python3 python3-pip python3-devel gcc openssl-devel libffi-devel python3-setuptools

RUN mkdir -p /home/app
COPY docker/pipeline /home/app

WORKDIR /home/app

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:5000", "main:app"]
```

Comment: @DeathMetal no :(

Comment: I was able to solve on my issue. 1 - I was using wrong image. Nextflow requires image 2- I had to receive arguments/variables using `path` keyword. Due to some drive-mount thing it doesn't like `file` keyword. I hope you're able to solve your docker-nextflow part. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @DeathMetal. I do not use `file` keyword. In my question I added the content of the docker file. The image I use is: `nextflow/nextflow:23.11.0-edge`